# c++ loop while child is alive

Tags: c++, posix, fork

After I fork in a c++ program.  What is the syntax to run a while loop until the child process dies.

```
int value = fork();
if( value = 0 ) {
    //do something
} else {
    while(childIsAlive) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

the do somethings are independent.

Comment: erm... I think it depends what //do something does? if it just one function that once it is done... then you don't need another loop. or is it a check to see if a second thread has finished? Need more info please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int Stat;
if (waitpid(PidOfChild, &Stat, WNOHANG) == PidOfChild) {
  if (WIFEXITED(Stat) || WIFSIGNALED(Stat)) {
    childAlive = false;
  }
}
```

waitpid wait's for a state change in waitpid. If it returns PidOfChild, there was a change, and Stat is updated.

WIFEXITED(Stat) will be true if the child process exited normally

WIFSIGNALED(Stat) will be true if the child process was terminated by a signal.

EDIT: Sample code.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  srand(time(0));

  pid_t pid = fork();

  if (pid == 0) {
    int Seconds = rand() % 3 + 1;
    cout << "child: Sleeping " << Seconds << " seconds" << endl;
    sleep(Seconds);
    if (rand() % 2) {
      cout << "child: Killing" << endl;
      kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
    } else {
      int ExitCode = rand() % 3;
      cout << "child: Exiting with exit code " << ExitCode << endl;
      exit(ExitCode);
    }
  } else if (pid > 0) {
    for (;;) {
      cout << "parent: spinning waiting for child to exit" << endl;
      int Stat;
      while (waitpid(pid, &Stat, WNOHANG) != pid);
      if (WIFEXITED(Stat)) {
        cout << "parent: Child exited with exit code " << WEXITSTATUS(Stat) << endl;
        break;
      } else if (WIFSIGNALED(Stat)) {
        cout << "parent: Child killed with signal " << WTERMSIG(Stat) << endl;
        break;
      } else {
        cout << "parent: Something else happened to child, e.g. STOPPED" << endl;
      }
    }

  } else {
    cout << "Error forking: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: It'll be updated by waitpid if anything happend to the child process's state. You use WIFEXITED/WIFSIGNALED to check *what* happened.

Comment: I believe I understand.  Gonna try that out.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.  I signal for the child process to exit and it's listed under ps as a defunct.  Is this correct?

Comment: It will be defunct until you've waited for it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was storing the stat_loc and waiting for it to change.  I believe I understand how I need to do this.  I'm running out for a bit and I'll try it when I get back. Once again, thanks.